# What is the execution model for nightwatch custom commands, and how do I wait for them?

Tags: javascript, testing, nightwatch.js

It appears that my custom commands implemented for Nightwatch.js are getting executed asynchronously. A `console.log` message inside the custom command is showing up *after* a `console.log` message issued from after the command is invoked. I can't find any reference in the nightwatch documentation about how these commands are executed, but since they appear to be asynchronous, I'm not sure how I can wait to make sure one command has completed before the next one is executed (because this doesn't not appear to be the case).

Here is my custom command ("foo"):

```
exports.command = function () {
    console.log('Command executed');
}
```

And my test function:

```
module.exports['my test'] = function(browser) {
    browser.resizeWindow(400, 600);
    browser.foo();
    console.log('Test function returning');
};
```

When I run this, the logs show up as:

```
Test function returning
Command executed
```

Which is the opposite order of what I would expect if my custom function was getting executed synchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your custom command to work properly (and be synch), you need to call at least one Nightwatch.js command inside your custom command.

Try this:

```
exports.command = function () {
    console.log('Command executed');
    this.execute(function() {});
}
```

If you want more in-depth details, you can follow this issue:
https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1123

Answer (score 0):

Your command should take `callback` as argument:

```js
exports.command = function (callback) {
    console.log('Command executed');
    if (callback) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

and execute like this:

```js
browser.foo(function() {
    console.log('Test function returning');
});
```

Another solution is to use the `browser.perform` method:

```js
module.exports['my test'] = function(browser) {
    browser.resizeWindow(400, 600);
    browser.foo();
    browser.perform(function()
        console.log('Test function returning');
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a horrible design by the Nightwatch team.  I just spent hours trying to debug this issue and the only solution that worked for me was to use a perform().  This is ridiculous.  Why in the world would the Nightwatch developers have custom commands run asynchronously.

Comment: This post reads more like a rant than an actual answer, and doesn't provide any new information over [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38963863). Rants about the shortcomings of a particular technology don't add anything to the post, and aren't very helpful for future readers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).